# Xcode: buidling binary with additional JSON and image content

Tags: json, swift, xcode, build

I'm writing an Elgato Streamdeck Plugin in Swift. See SDK overview: https://developer.elgato.com/documentation/stream-deck/sdk/overview/

Apart from building the plug-in binary, I also have to write a manfiest.json file with the config of the plug-in, create an "image" folder with some .PNGs and put everything into a folder, like "com.[MY_COMPANY].[MY_PLUGIN_NAME].sdPlugin"

Until now I only build the binary in Xcode and do the rest manually in Finder. I would like to have everything in my Xcode project and do this automatically. But how?

Thanks,
Stefan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution:

- select the project in project navigator and select the target
- under **Build phases -> Copy Files**, choose **Destination -> Absolute** and define the path
- uncheck **copy only when installing**
- add the desired files from the project navigator. In my case manifest.json from my source files and the plugin binary from **Products**